# Jackcess Numberformatexception

Tags: java, csv, numberformatexception, jackcess

I'm trying to create a program which takes input from a CSV-file and writes it to a Java-created Access database and table. The program uses a while-loop to go through the CSV-file. The first line of the file is written perfectly to the database, but it crashes at the second line, while trying to write the same kind of input to the table. How can I solve this? Here's my code so far:

```
public void GPXtoAccess() {
    try {
        Access = new Scanner(DummyCSV);
        Scanner = new Scanner(DummyCSV);

        while (Access.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner.useDelimiter(";");
            GPXlat = Scanner.next();
            GPXlon = Scanner.next();
            GPXtime = Scanner.next();
            GPXname = Scanner.next();
            GPXdesc = Scanner.next();

            try {
                GPXTable.addRow(Column.AUTO_NUMBER, GPXlat, GPXlon, GPXtime, GPXname, GPXdesc);
            } catch (IOException T) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + T);
                System.out.println("Error is thrown while writing data to table");
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException M) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + M);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have use `Scanner.next()` which returns `String` value. Most of the time your table column values not match with `String` that is why you getting `Numberformatexception`

Comment: I've set the datatype of that field to String so that it wouldn't be a problem. In the first line of the CSV it says "2016-11-28T11:57:38", which is properly written to the database. The second line reads "2016-11-28T11:36:34" and at that point the program throws the numberformatexception.

Comment: @HaroldFinch Try to set the field type to Object

Comment: I can choose from Binary, boolean, byte, complex_type, double, float, guid, int, long, memo, money, numeric, ole, short_date_time, text, unknown_od, unknown_11, unsupported_fixedlen and unsuppported_varlen...

Comment: @HaroldFinch what is the IDE you use ?

Comment: NetBeans 8.2, jackcess 2.1.8 & 2.1.9

Comment: @HaroldFinch Class[] types = new Class [] {} can you find this on code

Comment: Should I be using that as datatype?

Comment: @HaroldFinch in side this you can see the data types map to your column

Comment: Ok I've found Object, where should I put that? I'm kinda new to Java...

Comment: Class[] types = new Class [] {java.lang.Object.class,java.lang.Object.class}

Comment: This is what I got now: 
.addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("<time", DataType.Class[] types = new Class [] {java.lang.Object.class,java.lang.Object.class}))

It won't compile...

Comment: Nothing, it just gives a ton of errors like 'class expected' ';' expected and so on. Is there a way I can send you my code?

Comment: try java.lang.String.class instead of java.lang.Object.class

Comment: When I add your code, it says that I try to run uncompilable sourcecode. This is the line of code:

.addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("<time>", DataType.Class[] types = new Class [] { java.lang.String.class,java.lang.Object.class}))

Comment: Okay I'm trying to write a CSV-file into an Access Database. The datatype of the field which causes the problem is TEXT. The first line of the CSV-file is this:  52.341435;6.383002;2016-11-28T11:57:38;Foto 7;Wal + greppel, with the delimiter being ";". So far so good. The next line of the CSV-file contains similar data, only different numbers. But the program crashes when it tries to write 2016-11-28T11:57:38 into the database as being TEXT, throwing the numberformatexception. So in the first line, it works fine, but it crashes in the second line, trying to write almost the same data.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you may try to convert a String type one to a numeric type. Please check data types of your data that you are trying to use.

Comment: But it works fine in the first line! In the second line all the '-' and ':' are in the same place, only the numbers are slightly different